# Python circular import when accessing method from class in separate module

Tags: python

I have two modules and each module contains a class. In each module I want to reference methods from the class in the other module. I have setup a small class to help wrap my head around the concept. I imported one module into the other module, but I am still getting a circular import error. To my understanding this is the proper way to do it, but I am still getting an error.
Here are my example classes:

a.py module:

```
import b
class A():
    def __init__(self):
        print("A has run")
    def aa():
        print("aa has run")

b.B.bb()
```

b.py module:

```
import a
class B():
    def __init__(self):
        print("B has run")
    def bb():
        print("bb has run")
        # Run method from class in seperate module
        a.A.aa()
```

Here is my error:
`AttributeError: partially initialized module 'b' has no attribute 'B' (most likely due to a circular import)`

Comment: The simplest solution is just to put both classes in the same module. In any case, `a.A.aa()` and `b.B.bb()` don't make sense. Your methods aren't methods. So probably, just move those functions into their own module as module-level functions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `a.py` is importing `b.py` and `b.py` is importing `a.py`, that's a circular import. Typically you want to restructure your code so that your modules do not need to import each other. Without seeing more about your actual use case, it's hard to give advice, but it could be something like this:

a.py module:

```
class A():
    def __init__(self):
        print("A has run")
    def aa():
        print("aa has run")
```

b.py module:

```
import a
class B():
    def __init__(self):
        print("B has run")
    def bb():
        print("bb has run")
        # Run method from class in seperate module
        a.A.aa()
```

c.py module

```
import b
b.B.bb()
```

Comment: So I can't use circular imports at all? I was looking at this guide for reference and they say you can use circular imports if you access the class via the module like in this example https://sbcode.net/python/proxy/#avoiding-circular-imports

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really familiar with what's going on in this guide. It is possible that the guide you are looking at is outdated. I just can't think of any real-world scenario where you would _want_ to do circular imports

Comment: @TristanVerduzco you can, but you *shouldn't*

Answer (score 1):

You are right, that's due to circular import, and the reason is your import is at module level, instead if you exclude the module level import, you will not run in an issue, for example:

Modify your code like this:

```py
class A():
    def __init__(self):
        print("A has run")
    def aa():
        print("aa has run")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import b
    b.B.bb()
```

**OUTPUT**

```py
bb has run
aa has run
```

Now, you'll no longer get the `AttributeError` because now the module `b` is not being imported at module level in module `a`.

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a hack but the easiest (if hacky) way to get out of this is

```
class B():
    def __init__(self):
        print("B has run")
    def bb():
        print("bb has run")
        import a  # import on demand (each time)


        # Run method from class in seperate module
        a.A.aa()
```

A slightly better approach is to remember your import of a:

```
import b
class A():
    def __init__(self):
        print("A has run")
    def aa():
        print("aa has run")


print("running A")
b.B.bb()
b.B.bb()
```

```
class B():
    def __init__(self):
        print("B has run")
    def bb():
        print("bb has run")
        #remember your import of a
        a = getattr(B, "a", None)
        if not a:
            import a 
            B.a = a 

        # Run method from class in seperate module
        a.A.aa()
```

You'll notice that "running A" only happens twice:  once when you `python a.py` and then the first time b.B.bb() gets called and imports on demand.